# Overlay plots from PSpice - SIMetrix or SIMetrix to PSpice

Tags: simulation, spice, pspice, graph, modelling

I wanted to verify the accuracy of a identical model which I modelled, between PSpice and SIMetrix simulator

- I ran model in Pspice and SIMetrix separately and probed required nets (net names are identical in both the simulators)
- Saved the file of SIMetrix in `.dat` format and appended in PSpice as shown

[image: SIMetrix]

[image: PSpice]

[image: Error]

- So I tried another approach to overlay in MS-EXCEL or Libre office and exported the simulation plot in `.CSV` but I couldn't find option to export SIMetrix plot in `.CSV` or any other format.

Is there any different approach to do this exercise?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**This might be one of the alternatives**,

*OVERLAY from SIMetrix to PSpice*

- `Goto > SIMetrix simulation window >edit> copy ASCII data`
  [image: SIMetrix]
- Paste the data `cntrl+v` in Notepad and save it in `.txt`

[image: Output]

- Import the saved `.txt` in PSpice

[image: Pspice ovelay]

- Generate `.dat` using `.txt` file

Answer (score 0):

Overlaying plots of data seems like a poor way of verifying that two simulators produce the same results. You would be better off calculating the statistics of the difference between the logged data values, such as maximum difference and RMS difference. Be sure to log the data values as double-precision floating-point numbers and perform all of the calculations using double-precision arithmetic.

Keep in mind that this analysis tells you nothing about the **accuracy** of either simulator, only whether they are consistent with each other.

Comment: I wanted to check whether there is need in changing any .OPTIONS of any other factors while running in two simulators  the goal was to check the accuracy of the model not the simulator, i am not getting any cross platform (export data)to get those data from either of the plots as i mentioned in the question description.